# FlowJS union types with same deep type

Tags: flowtype

I have the following type

```
type segment = 
  | { created_in: {account_id : string}}
  | { updated_in: {account_id: string}};
```

With the following function dissecting the union:

```
const operate = (segment: segment): string => {
 if (segment.created_in) {
    return segment.created_in.account_id
  } else if (segment.updated_in) {
    return segment.updated_in.account_id;
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Flow gives an error on `segment.created_in.account_id`:

```
10:     return segment.created_in.account_id                               
^ Cannot get `segment.created_in.account_id` because property `account_id` is missing in property `created_in` of unknown type [1].
References:
9:  if (segment.created_in) {
        ^ [1]
```

Why can't `if (segment.created_in)` determine that were in the `{created_in: { account_id: string}` branch?

Comment: Maybe no something suitable for you, but you can: `type segment = { [s: 'created_in' | 'updated_in'] : {account_id : string}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by using exact object types for the branches of `segment` like this:

```
type segment =
  | {| created_in: { account_id: string, foo: number } |}
  | {| updated_in: { account_id: string } |};
```

The exact object syntax, `{| ... |}`, tells Flow that objects of the given type may not have properties other than the ones that are listed. By default object types are "open": objects of the given type must have the properties in the type definition, but may have additional properties.

With the default inexact types Flow cannot narrow the types according to your checks because it does not know for certain that an object with the property `created_in` does not also have a property called `updated_in`. And if it does have such a property, Flow does not know what the type would be because that property is not given in the type declaration. That is why the error that you see mentions an `unknown type`.

Comment: This explanation was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!